# Updating nested UICollectionView - Swift 3

Tags: swift, firebase, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, reloaddata

I've got problem with updating my UICollectionView. I've got the following setup, which consists out of nested collectionViews.

[image]

The homeControllerView is a collectionViewController with the CollectionView 1, with paging enabled. Every cell of CollectionView 1 is a collectionView for itself, e.g. CollectionView A, B, ... The reason for this is, every CollectionView A, B, ... is a feed, that fetches information which is then displayed as Cells A1, A2, B1 ...

When the HomeViewController is loaded all CollectionViews A, B ... are populated, every (Main)Cell 1, 2, will start fetching information. Some of the feeds are fetching personal information, that a bound to the current user which is logged in.

After switching to another user, I'd like to have the (Main)collectionView to update, so that all Cell 1, 2, ... are staring to fetch the information again. So out of my LoginController I call

```
self.homeController?.collectionView?.reloadData()
```

But that only seems to work for the cell which is currently visible, e.g. Cell 2 in the displayed example. Also reloading items only work for those that are visible:

```
self.homeController?.collectionView?.reloadItems(at: (self.homeController?.collectionView?.indexPathsForVisibleItems)!)
```

In my homeViewController I override the cellForItem function like this

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    switch indexPath.item {
        case 0:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: incomingFeedCellId, for: indexPath) as! IncomingFeedCell
            return cell
        case 1:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: popularFeedCellId, for: indexPath) as! PopularFeedCell
            return cell
        case 2:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: favoritFeedCellId, for: indexPath) as! FavoritFeedCell
            return cell
        case 3:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: personalFeedCellId, for: indexPath) as! PersonalFeedCell
            return cell
        default:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: incomingFeedCellId, for: indexPath) as! IncomingFeedCell
            return cell
    }
}
```

But with `.reloadData()` the cellForItem function is not called again, so once initiated, the cells won't update again.

Every FeedCell has a fetch() function which is called at least once the cell is created:

```
func fetch(){
    posts = [Post]()
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    ref.child("posts_incoming").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
            let post = Post()
            post.imageUrl = dictionary["image_url"] as? String
            post.caption = dictionary["caption"] as? String
            ...
            ...
            self.posts?.append(post)

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Currently I keep track of the userId within the (Main)Cells so, when the Cell is dequeued (e.g. swiping to the next feed) it checks, if the uid has changed, and if so, fetch will be executed again... but I'm sure the must be a more elegant solution for this problem. Is there a way, to discard all cells and force a new initialization for each cell?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a custom class of `UICollectionView` and all the feed fetching calls should be made in  custom `UICollectionView` class.
Also to keep it simple ,like not nesting `UICollectionViews`,you can use :

Main UICollectionView for Paging and add UITableview inside cell of `UICollectionView`.

So the reloading would be like:

> UICollectionView in UIViewController
>
> UITableview in UICollectionView Custom class

Also you must use `dequeueReusableCell` always otherwise too much memory will be allocated making your app crash.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yet I don't understand how this could help. If I'll create CollectionView 1 as a custom CollectionView with a new function from which I would update the cells, I still have no access to those cells that are not visible, right?

Comment: Yeah look if you have fixed 5 super cells, you can do one thing, user ScrollView whose content size is 5 times the view. Then add 5 container views containing separating UIViewControllers in each containerView.
This way you can easily manage everything.